# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found when using custom Dialect

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, jboss7.x

Hello I'm trying to find a solution for Oracle conversions problem (doesn't accept "number" to be Double) with JBoss 7.1 and Hibernate. So, best suggested solution was to make a custom Dialect this way :

```
public class MyOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
public MyOracle10gDialect() {
    super();
}
protected void registerNumericTypeMappings() {
    super.registerNumericTypeMappings();
    registerColumnType( Types.DOUBLE, "number" );
}}
```

In the hibernate.cfg.xml I added :

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.d2i.sssim.hibercommun.MyOracle10gDialect</property>
```

But this is what I got :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: com.d2i.sssim.hibercommun.MyOracle10gDialect

It's about the same project, with hibernate connection. Should I really create another project with one class (MyOracle10gDialect) and include it in my project as a lib? Why the hibernate.cfg.xml can't see the classes in it's own project? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using Hibernate as JBoss module and as such it cannot see your custom class in your application. You can try to deploy your dialect classes as a custom [JBoss module](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7).